# White screen when trying to redirect to page following successful sql statement

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to redirect to a new page once data is successfully added into the sql table, however when I enter the

```
header("location: success.php");
                exit;
```

code, I just get a white screen when loading the page.

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
        /* when the submit button in the modal is clicked, submit the form */
        <?php 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT(Weekstart, Day, APTime) VALUES ('01-01-2020', 'T', '9:00')";

         if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            header("location: success.php");
            exit;
         } else {
            header("location: no.php");
            exit;
}
        ?>
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried writing "Location" instead of "location"? Do you have any error like "Header already sent"?

Comment: Making it uppercase didn't work, I'm not receiving any errors in chrome

Comment: when I remove the exit statements I get a header already sent error

Comment: If you're code is exactly as written (i.e. PHP generating the page, mixed with the generated JS), it won't work because before the header() statement you have already sent content to the browser (HTML and JS). You should move the PHP code handling the form submission at the top of your code, or even better to its own file, and retry

Comment: Javascript runs in clinet-side and php runs in server-side. for this one you must use ajax or form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using php code inside javascript code.

It will execute on page load itself and not on button click.

Create a sperate php file and put your php code in it. Lets say test.php and use blewo form in modal no javascipt required.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
/* your input parameters*/
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: is there any way around this?